# Unable to render actions buttons in a react table

Tags: reactjs, react-table

I have react-table which is a simple CRUD application. I have a delete button for each row to delete that record.

In my implementation when I try it with `static data`, it works fine.

But when I do it via making API calls, the `delete button` does not render.

I am basically creating a delete button dynamically and performing actions on it.

**Problem is, that the below implementation works with static data but not with dynamic data (data from api)**

[Link to the static data example](https://demos.creative-tim.com/black-dashboard-pro-react/#/documentation/react-table)

API calls approach:

```
const AdminAPInfo = [];
    this.state = {
      apiInfo: AdminAPInfo.map((prop, uuid) => {
        return {
          id: uuid,
          name: prop[0],
          actions: (
            <div className="actions-right">
              <Button
                fill="true"
                onClick={() => {
                  var data = this.state.data;
                  data.find((o, i) => {
                    if (o.id === uuid) {
                     data.splice(i, 1);
                      console.log(data);
                      console.log(i);
                      return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                  });
                  this.setState({
                    data: data,
                  });
                }}
                color="danger"
                size="sm"
                className="btn-icon btn-link remove"
                id="tooltip974171201"
              >
                <i className="fa fa-times" />
              </Button>
            </div>
          ),
        };
      }),
    };
  }
```

and this react-table component

```
<ReactTable
   data={apiInfo}
    columns={[
       {
        Header: "API Name",
          accessor: "name",
        },
        {
     Header: "Actions",
       accessor: "actions",
         sortable: false,
         ilterable: false,
        },
      ]}
```

[Link to my code in codeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-johnson-m4vu6?file=/src/ReactTable.js)

Comment: can you post full code of component or if possible a codesandbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call this convert method at render each time.

Check this codesandbox

https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-cloud-9xwx8

What you were doing is setting the rendered data at `componentDidMount` but then you were using the json returned from API call.
So you need everytime to call this convert function.

Comment: aah.. understood. quick question though, the delete doesn't seem to work anymore. But it works in the static example I had shared

Comment: was just about to send the fix :) glad you found it :)

Comment: I removed the tooltip because i couldnt' click the button and also used filter function in order to reduce code. check the updated link :)